# SharePoint user can't see site despite being in AD group

Tags: 2013, permissions, active-directory, groups

I have a problem where when I give permission to an AD group to a site on SharePoint, the site does not show to the people in that group.

It shows when they are in a normal SharePoint group but not when they are in an AD group.

This is the group i'm trying to give access to.

[image: This is the group in AD]

Here it is in the permission list

[image]

How it looks to a central administrator

[image]

How it looks to someone in "Accounts Department"

[image]

Comment: since this looks like a custom masterpage/css, do you have everything checked in and published?

Comment: First: With the group added, Use the "check permissions" button to verify that the people have access to the site. Second: If they have the link to the Subsidiaries site, do they get an Access Denied page?

Comment: Hello both, all masterpages are checked in, so no problems there. I did "Check Permission" and got this message:  "Permission levels given to domain\username None" and when they try visit the link they get a "Access Required" message.

Comment: Do you have multiple domains in your environment?

Comment: No only the one domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I managed to figure this out myself eventually.

Turns out I was putting a domain group inside a SharePoint group, where as you need to put it in the root access of the permissions.

As you can see in the image below, originally i had added it to "Subsidiaries Members", after removing it from there and re-adding it to the "root" permission list, everyone in "Accounts Department" was able to see the site.

[image]